# How do you delete system messages from sys.messages in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I'm working on DB Migration project where I have to migrate databases from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016.

In SQL Server 2008 my team has used to throw custom exceptions using `RAISERROR` with `message_id` less than 50000. They have deleted system message id with 35100 from `sys.messages` which usually throws:

> Error number %d in the THROW statement is outside the valid range. Specify an error number in the valid range of 50000 to 2147483647.

Now I would like to delete same message id (`35100`) from `sys.messages` table, I cannot use custom messages because I have to do lot of changes in application.

I want to throw this custom exception using throw when I pass below parameters

```
Throw 19175,'19175|WARNING - Confirm Update  ; Error = 19175',1
```

> Msg 19175, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
> 19175|WARNING - Confirm Update  ; Error = 19175

I tried below approaches but failed

- Tried to login with admin account (Admin:Instance)
- Tried to delete rows in hidden database mssqlsystemresource
- Tried with `SP_Configure 'allow updates'`

Please explain how I can delete this message id from `sys.messages` (view), or how I can show the custom exception in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Dropping an error with a value of 50,000 or less seems like bad idea. User defined error messages are meant to have a value greater than 50,000.

Comment: yes, but I need to know a way how I can delete a message from sys.messages table

Comment: The `sys` things are **system catalog views** - first of all, those are **system**-level things - not user - and second they are views - both points are clear hints that you ***CANNOT*** under any circumstance just delete something from them ....

Comment: but I cannot see the same exception message in my old database(SQL 2008), how is it possible for them?

Comment: Have you tried `sp_dropmessage`?

Comment: The code behind `sp_dropmessage` says "Message id must be > 50000 (unless SQL Server is in single user mode)" - I don't want to mess up my own instance by trying it in single user mode to see if it works like that

Comment: I tried `sp_dropmessage` with single user mode also it says 'Cannot drop a message with an ID less than 50,000.'

Comment: I really suggest you use a User Error messages with an ID of greater than 50,000, @raj , like you're suppose to.

Comment: "I cannot use custom messages because I have to do lot of changes in application." That's not a technical limitation. How much work would it be to do `select object_name(object_id) from sys.sql_modules where definition like '%RAISERROR%'` to identify code that needs changing and then do a bulk replace of error numbers? As many others have said in comments, what you're trying to do seems like a *really bad idea*.